# Using R how to identify specific pattern in columns of dataframe and substitute with pattern(s) of interest?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, substring, data-cleaning

In the dataframe file `DT`, `Var1` is unique.The `ID` split into `Spl_1` & `Spl_2` by the first three characters/digits. In addition, the `DT` was `group_by` the `Spl_2`. Hence there are four groups:

```
 - KLM001 
 - OKT004    
 - MLO010      
 - AAA008
```

The dataframe file:

```
DT
    ID         Spl_1 Spl_2  Var1
1   001KLM001   001 KLM001  xx
2   001KLM001   001 KLM001  rr
3   044KLM001   044 KLM001  qwe
4   023OKT004   023 OKT004  sdf
5   023OKT004   023 OKT004  dfg
6   023OKT004   023 OKT004  ssg
7   023OKT004   023 OKT004  htj
8   023OKT004   023 OKT004  yjy
9   001OKT004   001 OKT004  wttt
10  054MLO010   054 MLO010  dg
11  023MLO011   023 MLO010  asd
12  001AAA008   001 AAA008  dggj
13  001AAA008   001 AAA008  sfe
14  001AAA008   001 AAA008  lkyt
15  056AAA008   056 AAA008  fghe
16  123AAA008   123 AAA008  wert
```

**Conditions:** 
Although the `Spl_2` are identical for grouped strings, but the `Spl_1` are different. (*e.g.* for `KLM001`  there are two `Spl_1`: `001` & `044`). 
The majority of the grouped stings have `Spl_1` `001` which is of the main interest. Anything except the `Spl_1` `001` is a kind of artifact and needs to be identified and replaced by `001`. 
 **NOTE** However, if the grouped `Spl_2` *dose not have any* `Spl_1` with `001` should be kept intact. In this example (`DT`) it is `MLO010`   which only has `Spl_1`: `054` & `023`.

**Intention:** 
Based on the grouped `Spl_2`, look at the `Spl_1` and see if there is `001` among them. If so, then replace the `non 001` `Spl_1` with `001` and attached it with the `Spl_2` and put it into the new column called  `Cor_ID` while keeping the entire `DT`.

**The expected output:**

```
    ID         Spl_1 Spl_2  Var1     Cor_ID 
1   001KLM001   001 KLM001  xx      001KLM001
2   001KLM001   001 KLM001  rr      001KLM001
3   044KLM001   044 KLM001  qwe     001KLM001
4   023OKT004   023 OKT004  sdf     001OKT004
5   023OKT004   023 OKT004  dfg     001OKT004
6   023OKT004   023 OKT004  ssg     001OKT004
7   023OKT004   023 OKT004  htj     001OKT004
8   023OKT004   023 OKT004  yjy     001OKT004
9   001OKT004   001 OKT004  wttt    001OKT004   
10  054MLO010   054 MLO010  dg      054MLO010
11  023MLO011   023 MLO010  asd     023MLO010
12  001AAA008   001 AAA008  dggj    001AAA008
13  001AAA008   001 AAA008  sfe     001AAA008
14  001AAA008   001 AAA008  lkyt    001AAA008
15  056AAA008   056 AAA008  fghe    001AAA008
16  123AAA008   123 AAA008  wert    001AAA008
```

I am newbie in `r`. But I think I can do this with `gsub`. However, I do not know how exactly?

Comment: @Parfait , Corrected ! tnx :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak tnx, I read and understood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in a few ways, here it is with `data.table`:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( DT )

DT[ , Cor_ID := 
        if( "001" %in% Spl_1 ) { 
            paste0( "001", Spl_2 ) 
        } else {
            paste0( Spl_1, Spl_2 )
        }, 
    by = Spl_2 ]
```

So we're analysing the table grouped by `Spl_2` (the `by` parameter). The `if` conditions checks if "001" exists in the `Spl_1` column, and if so, pastes "001" and `Spl_2` together, otherwise pastes `Spl_1` and `Spl_2` together.

The result:

```
> DT
#           ID Spl_1  Spl_2 Var1    Cor_ID
#  1: 001KLM001   001 KLM001   xx 001KLM001
#  2: 001KLM001   001 KLM001   rr 001KLM001
#  3: 044KLM001   044 KLM001  qwe 001KLM001
#  4: 023OKT004   023 OKT004  sdf 001OKT004
#  5: 023OKT004   023 OKT004  dfg 001OKT004
#  6: 023OKT004   023 OKT004  ssg 001OKT004
#  7: 023OKT004   023 OKT004  htj 001OKT004
#  8: 023OKT004   023 OKT004  yjy 001OKT004
#  9: 001OKT004   001 OKT004 wttt 001OKT004
# 10: 054MLO010   054 MLO010   dg 054MLO010
# 11: 023MLO011   023 MLO011  asd 023MLO011
# 12: 001AAA008   001 AAA008 dggj 001AAA008
# 13: 001AAA008   001 AAA008  sfe 001AAA008
# 14: 001AAA008   001 AAA008 lkyt 001AAA008
# 15: 056AAA008   056 AAA008 fghe 001AAA008
# 16: 123AAA008   123 AAA008 wert 001AAA008
```

Similarly, with `dplyr`:

```
library( dplyr )
DT %<>%
    group_by( Spl_2 ) %>%
    mutate( Cor_ID = 
                if( "001" %in% Spl_1 ) { 
                    paste0( "001", Spl_2 ) 
                } else {
                    paste0( Spl_1, Spl_2 )
                } )
```

The result:

```
> DT
# Source: local data frame [16 x 5]
# Groups: Spl_2 [5]
# 
#           ID Spl_1  Spl_2  Var1    Cor_ID
#        <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr>
# 1  001KLM001   001 KLM001    xx 001KLM001
# 2  001KLM001   001 KLM001    rr 001KLM001
# 3  044KLM001   044 KLM001   qwe 001KLM001
# 4  023OKT004   023 OKT004   sdf 001OKT004
# 5  023OKT004   023 OKT004   dfg 001OKT004
# 6  023OKT004   023 OKT004   ssg 001OKT004
# 7  023OKT004   023 OKT004   htj 001OKT004
# 8  023OKT004   023 OKT004   yjy 001OKT004
# 9  001OKT004   001 OKT004  wttt 001OKT004
# 10 054MLO010   054 MLO010    dg 054MLO010
# 11 023MLO011   023 MLO011   asd 023MLO011
# 12 001AAA008   001 AAA008  dggj 001AAA008
# 13 001AAA008   001 AAA008   sfe 001AAA008
# 14 001AAA008   001 AAA008  lkyt 001AAA008
# 15 056AAA008   056 AAA008  fghe 001AAA008
# 16 123AAA008   123 AAA008  wert 001AAA008
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider a base R with `ave`, assuming *001* will always be the minimum *Sp1_1* value:

```
DT$CorID <- ifelse(ave(DT$Spl_1, DT$Spl_2, FUN=min)!='001', paste0(DT$Spl_1, DT$Spl_2), paste0("001", DT$Spl_2))

#           ID Spl_1  Spl_2 Var1     CorID
# 1  001KLM001   001 KLM001   xx 001KLM001
# 2  001KLM001   001 KLM001   rr 001KLM001
# 3  044KLM001   044 KLM001  qwe 001KLM001
# 4  023OKT004   023 OKT004  sdf 001OKT004
# 5  023OKT004   023 OKT004  dfg 001OKT004
# 6  023OKT004   023 OKT004  ssg 001OKT004
# 7  023OKT004   023 OKT004  htj 001OKT004
# 8  023OKT004   023 OKT004  yjy 001OKT004
# 9  001OKT004   001 OKT004 wttt 001OKT004
# 10 054MLO010   054 MLO010   dg 054MLO010
# 11 023MLO011   023 MLO011  asd 023MLO011
# 12 001AAA008   001 AAA008 dggj 001AAA008
# 13 001AAA008   001 AAA008  sfe 001AAA008
# 14 001AAA008   001 AAA008 lkyt 001AAA008
# 15 056AAA008   056 AAA008 fghe 001AAA008
# 16 123AAA008   123 AAA008 wert 001AAA008
```